# How to checkout to the contents of a specific commit only?

Tags: git, version-control

I have an `old_branch` where I do some prototyping stuff only on a few files in my code. My `master` branch is way ahead of the `old_branch`, so when I

```
git checkout old_branch -- .
```

from `master`, *I get a lot of in-between commits to my index*. I know how to extract just the files I need with the syntax:

```
git checkout old_branch -- file1
git checkout old_branch -- file2
...
git checkout old_branch -- fileN
```

but when the number of these files is large, the task becomes rather cumbersome.

So how can I get to the contents of this specific commit (tip of the `old_branch`) from `master` with a one-liner and without seeing in index other changes from the in-between commits?

Comment: Commits in git are _snapshots_ of the code base, so a commit contains all the files in the repo at the time it was made. Are you looking to check out only files that were _changed_ in a particular commit? It would also be useful to understand _why_ you're doing this, rather than checking out the branch itself, or merging it with `master`.

Comment: Yes, I want to checkout only the files that were changed in this particular commit (but all of them).

Comment: Why can't you just do `git checkout old_branch`? (without `-- .`)

Comment: The reasons are as follows:
1. When I checkout the branch, I leave behind all my current development, and this is what I want to test: old prototyping stuff on new settings.

2. When I merge old_branch (say with -X theirs --no-commit --no-ff to avoid merge conflicts and to store evertyhing in index) I receive some other in-between files which were not changed in old_branch.

Comment: @Maverick That last statement smells fishy to me. If you're on `master` and run `git merge old_branch`, there is nothing "in between", git is merging all the commits on `old_branch` that are not on `master`. There may be some deeper confusion here about what commits you expect to be included when you reference `my_branch`.

Comment: You are probably right:) I'm not a git expert and still need to learn the ropes. Your answer is very helpful, so thank you.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to look at the commit graph from `git`'s point of view, and try to understand what it's bringing in when you run `git merge`, rather than just running commands that you don't fully understand. A view I often use is `git log --oneline --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset %C(yellow)%d%Creset %s' --color master old_branch`. `git log master...old_branch` may also be helpful.

Comment: I will look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just use [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) for this:

```
git cherry-pick old_branch --no-commit
```

The [`--no-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt---no-commit) option will apply the changes introduced by the commit referenced by `old_branch` to your index and working directory, but it won't create a commit on `master`.

Comment: It's important to note that cherry-pick expects a _commit_, not a _branch_, so the example shown will only apply the single commit on the tip of `old_branch`. If you want to cherry-pick multiple commits, you have to specify a range in some form.

Comment: This solves the problem because `git cherry-pick commit-ish` only applies the changes introduced by the specified commit. A branch ref always resolves to a single commit, so `git cherry-pick old_branch` does what OP asked for.  
If you look at `cherry-pick`'s [source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0/builtin/revert.c#L236-L247), you'll see that it eventually runs [`git reset --merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---merge), which only modifies the files that are different between the specified commit and `HEAD`.

Comment: To put it another way, the question says "I have some changes on a branch", not "I have a commit on a branch"; so there is no reason to _assume_ that the changes are all in the tip commit of that branch.

Comment: If you read the last paragraph of the question, you'll see that OP explicitly asked "_how can I get to the contents of this specific commit (tip of the `old_branch`) from `master`_".

Comment: You're absolutely right, I completely missed that sentence! I was confused by the first half of the question talking about the unexpected "extra" changes. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of git concepts to have clear in your head before proceeding with this:

- a commit contains a full snapshot of the repository at that time, not a set of changes
- a branch is just a convenient pointer to a commit (and from there to the history of that commit), not an actual set of commits

With this in mind, we can more clearly define the requirement:

- check out from the commit currently pointed to by branch `old_branch` (the "tip" of the branch)
- ... those files which were changed by any of the commits ... (more pedantically, those files which differ from their parent commit)
- ... reachable from `old_branch` but not reachable from `master` (what we would intuitively understand as the commits "on" the `old_branch` branch)

There are probably multiple ways to do this, but given the above definition, we could string something together:

- as you say in the question, `git checkout old_branch --` lets us checkout selected files; importantly for our purposes, it can take any number of arguments
- `git diff --name-only` will give us a list of files that were changed between some pair of commits
- the special notation `master...old_branch` passed to `git diff` will [as the manual puts it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) "view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second , starting at a common ancestor of both "; in this case, it will find the point where `old_branch` branched from `master`, and compare that against the current tip of `old_branch`

The final piece of the puzzle is the Unix command `xargs` which can take a list of values produced by one command and turn it into arguments for another. So we end up with this:

```
git diff --name-only master...old_branch | xargs git checkout old_branch --
```

---

As an aside, this will completely overwrite those files with the version in `old_branch`. I presume you have a good reason to want this, but it is much more common to want to apply the *changes* from `old_branch`, which is as simple as:

```
git merge old_branch
```